# Find and copy files between two directories

Tags: file, copy

I need a recommendation for software, script, whatever tool which would let me easily find and copy files from source directory to destination, which copies/replaces the file only when the destination directory doesn't contain the specified file or it contains the file with different content (eg. using hash comparision).
Thanks in advance.
Kris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found Meld on Ubuntu to do just that, but at the end of the day I have created small java utility using apache utils to resolve my problem